# Convert a standard linq query to generic for implement

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code with linq query:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var allProfessionals = new Collection<Professional>
         {
             new Professional { Name = "Bruno Paulovich Silva" },
             new Professional { Name = "Ivan Silva Paulovich Bruno"},
             new Professional { Name = "Camila Campos"}
         };

        var namesSearch = new[] {"bruno", "silva"};

        var query = namesSearch.Aggregate(allProfessionals.AsQueryable(), (current, nome) => current.Where(oh => oh.Name.ToLower().Contains(nome.ToLower())));

        foreach (var res in query.ToList())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(res.Name.ToLower());
        }
    }
}
```

The result is:

```
Bruno Paulovich Silva
Silva Paulovich Bruno
```

I wonder know how I could turn linq query Aggregate for a generic method where I can re-use at another time.

in the example below I show what I understand of a generic query that is uses in the project:

```
public IQueryable<T> QueryBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> criteria)
{
    return DbSet.Where(criteria);
}
```

ps: sorry for my bad english

Comment: Is it just an example to use Aggregate somehow? I think you may simplify your query (and make it little bit faster)

Comment: How is the Aggregate function not already generic?

Comment: the question is edited with what I understand about generic query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I implement a method for LikeBy where an array of string is equivalent to a contains all.

```
public IQueryable<T> LikeBy(string[] strings, Func<IQueryable<T>, string, IQueryable<T>> criteria)
{
    return strings.Aggregate(GetAll(), criteria);
}
```

Here the example of how implement:

```
public IQueryable<ViaturaFuncao> FindByNome(string names)
{
    return Uow.Professional.LikeBy(names.Trim().Split(' '),
                                       (professional, nameProfessional) =>
                                       professional.Where(
                                           f => f.Name.ToLower().Contains(nameProfessional.ToLower())));
}
```

PS: In the project we're using UnitOfWork and that is why has the UOW before the entity

Answer (score 2):

Sticking to bare essentials and to the same output as your script, it would be something like:

```c#
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var allProfessionals =
            new Collection<Professional>
                {
                    new Professional {Name = "Bruno Paulovich Silva"},
                    new Professional {Name = "Ivan Silva Paulovich Bruno"},
                    new Professional {Name = "Camila Campos"}
                };

        var namesSearch = new[] {"bruno", "silva"};

        var items = allProfessionals
            .Select(x => x.Name)
            .ContainsAll(namesSearch);

        foreach (var res in items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(res);
        }
    }
}

static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> ContainsAll(this IEnumerable<string> haystacks, IEnumerable<string> needles)
    {
        var lowerNeedles = needles.Select(x => x.ToLower()).ToList();
        var lowerHay = haystacks.Select(x => x.ToLower()).ToList();

        // note that Regex may be faster than .Contains with larger haystacks
        return lowerNeedles
            .Where(hay => lowerHay.All(hay.Contains)); // or .Any(), depending on your requirements
    }
}
```

Note that if you use LinqToSQL or similar technologies, table indexes may not be used. This may render the query very slow.

In order to make it fit with the mentioned `QueryBy<T>` it may look like:

```c#
        var items = allProfessionals.QueryBy(
            professional => namesSearch
                .Select(needle => needle.ToLower()) // convert all to lower case
                .All(hay => professional.Name.ToLower().Contains(hay))); // then try to search for a professional that matches all nameSearch.
```

Comment: Thanks for help Caramiriel. Your code works well but is not necessarily what I was wanting. I apologize if I was not clear in the question.